# Android Translate Animation Not being in front

Tags: android, android-animation

I have the following XML code which is not an Activity but is component that will be recycled throught many Activities:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#73808080">

    <LinearLayout android:layout_weight="1" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_height="0dp" android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_weight="30" android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_height="0dp" android:layout_width="match_parent">
            <LinearLayout android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_width="0dp"/>
            <LinearLayout android:layout_weight="10" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_width="0dp">
                <LinearLayout android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
                <LinearLayout android:layout_weight="18" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:orientation="vertical">
                    <TextView android:id="@+id/roundLabel" android:layout_weight="4" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="0dp" android:autoSizeTextType="uniform" android:gravity="center" android:fontFamily="@font/segoeui" android:textColor="@android:color/white" android:text="Round"/>
                    <TextView android:id="@+id/roundValue" android:layout_weight="10" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="0dp" android:autoSizeTextType="uniform" android:gravity="center" android:fontFamily="@font/segoeui" android:textColor="@android:color/white" android:text="1" android:textStyle="bold"/>
                    <TextView android:id="@+id/ofLabel" android:layout_weight="4" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="0dp" android:autoSizeTextType="uniform" android:gravity="center" android:fontFamily="@font/segoeui" android:textColor="@android:color/white" android:text="of"/>
                    <TextView android:id="@+id/roundsLabel" android:layout_weight="6" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="0dp" android:autoSizeTextType="uniform" android:gravity="center" android:fontFamily="@font/segoeui" android:textColor="@android:color/white" android:text="10" android:textStyle="bold"/>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout android:layout_weight="30" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_width="0dp" android:orientation="vertical">
                <OpenDarts.Android.Components.Label android:id="@+id/playerNameLabel" android:layout_weight="4" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="0dp" app:text="Player 1"/>
                <LinearLayout android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="0dp"/>
                <LinearLayout android:layout_weight="16" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="0dp" android:orientation="horizontal">
                    <com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView android:id="@+id/userPhoto" android:layout_weight="10" android:src="@drawable/avatar" android:scaleType="fitCenter" android:adjustViewBounds="true" app:riv_corner_radius="30dip" app:riv_corner_radius_top_left="30dip" app:riv_corner_radius_top_right="30dip" app:riv_corner_radius_bottom_right="30dip" app:riv_corner_radius_bottom_left="30dip" app:riv_border_width="0dip" app:riv_mutate_background="true" app:riv_tile_mode="clamp" app:riv_oval="true" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
                    <LinearLayout android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
                    <LinearLayout android:layout_weight="10" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:orientation="vertical">
                        <FrameLayout android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="0dp">
                            <ImageView android:id="@+id/dart1" android:src="@drawable/dart" android:adjustViewBounds="true" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
                            <TextView android:id="@+id/dart1Value" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:autoSizeTextType="uniform" android:gravity="center" android:fontFamily="@font/segoeui" android:textColor="@android:color/white" android:text=""/>
                        </FrameLayout>
                        <FrameLayout android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="0dp">
                            <ImageView android:id="@+id/dart2" android:src="@drawable/dart" android:adjustViewBounds="true" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
                            <TextView android:id="@+id/dart2Value" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:autoSizeTextType="uniform" android:gravity="center" android:fontFamily="@font/segoeui" android:textColor="@android:color/white" android:text=""/>
                        </FrameLayout>
                        <FrameLayout android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="0dp">
                            <ImageView android:id="@+id/dart3" android:src="@drawable/dart" android:adjustViewBounds="true" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
                            <TextView android:id="@+id/dart3Value" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:autoSizeTextType="uniform" android:gravity="center" android:fontFamily="@font/segoeui" android:textColor="@android:color/white" android:text=""/>
                        </FrameLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_width="0dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_weight="1" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_height="0dp" android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

From the Code Behind it triggers an animation on the ImageView with names: dart1, dart2, dart3. My problem is the animation is not being bring to the top. Instead, the image starts moving and stops on the very first "FrameLayout". I wanted the ImageView to being kept on top of everything.

The code Behind can be simplified as follows:

```
TranslateAnimation TranslateAnimation1 = new TranslateAnimation(0, 2000, 0, 0);
TranslateAnimation1.Duration = duration;
TranslateAnimation1.FillAfter = true;
TranslateAnimation1.AnimationEnd += TranslateAnimation1_AnimationEnd;
TranslateAnimation1.ZAdjustment = ContentZorder.Top;
dart1.StartAnimation(translateAnimation);
```

I have tried to use dart1.BringToFront() but without sucess.

PS: This is Xamarin.Android, but the API is identical to the native SDK, with slightly changes like names being Pascal Case and other slight changes.

Comment: If you want to ImageView to being kept on top of everything, you can change the outside `LinearLayout` to `RelativeLayout`, then put the Imageview at the bottom of the xml.

Comment: it will always stop at the FrameLayout, since it is inside it. You will have to animate the FrameLayout itself or put the ImageViews in a parent LinearLayout